# Element overflow hidden in React-Native Android

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I have an app here where I need to put the logo in the navbar. That need to overflow the scene layout. Work well in Ios with no problem but in android seem like he not working. I put the code at the bottom of the images. As you can see I use EStyleSheet so that let me use %.

IOS

[image]

Android

[image]

```
import React from 'react';
import { Scene, Router } from 'react-native-router-flux';
import EStyleSheet from 'react-native-extended-stylesheet';
import { View, Platform } from 'react-native';
import { SmallLogo } from './components';
import { checkColor } from './helpers';
import {
  HomeScreen,
  ImagePickerScreen,
  WaitingResponseScreen,
  ResultsScreen
} from './modules';
import Colors from '../constants/Colors';

const styles = EStyleSheet.create({
  navStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: '5%',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  logoCircle: {
    backgroundColor: '$whiteColor',
    height: 60,
    width: 60,
    borderRadius: 30,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  }
});

const logoNav = result => (
  <View style={styles.navStyle}>
    <View style={styles.logoCircle}>
      <SmallLogo color={checkColor(result)} />
    </View>
  </View>
);

const pdTop = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 64 : 54;

export default () => (
  <Router
    sceneStyle={{ paddingTop: pdTop }}
    navigationBarStyle={{ backgroundColor: Colors.greenColor }}
    renderTitle={props => {
      if (props.result) {
        return logoNav(props.result);
      }
      return logoNav(null);
    }}
    backButtonTextStyle={{ color: Colors.whiteColor }}
    leftButtonIconStyle={{ tintColor: Colors.whiteColor }}
  >
    <Scene
      key="home"
      component={HomeScreen}
    />
    <Scene
      key="imagesPicker"
      hideBackImage
      component={ImagePickerScreen}
    />
    <Scene
      key="waitingResponse"
      backTitle="Back"
      component={WaitingResponseScreen}
    />
    <Scene
      key="results"
      backTitle="Back"
      initial
      component={ResultsScreen}
    />
  </Router>
);
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In Android you cannot draw outside of the component's boundaries, which is a very annoying thing. I usually do the following as a workaround: Wrap your component in a new `<View>` that wraps both the former container and the overflowing data. Set the view `backgroundColor` to `'transparent'` so that it is invisible, and the `pointerEvents` prop to `'box-none'`, so that events get propagated to children. The dimensions of the view should be those of the former top component plus the overflow (in your case, it is just the height), but I think this should also work with Flexbox nicely in some circumstances.

Answer (score 11):

This is as pretty epic known issue.

- Github issue from 2015
  [overflow:hidden in React-Native Android](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3198)
- React Native Known Issus page
  [The overflow style property defaults to hidden and cannot be changed on Android](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.26/docs/known-issues.html#the-overflow-style-property-defaults-to-hidden-and-cannot-be-changed-on-android)
- Top trending feature request on the official React Native request board.
  [Feature Requests - React Native](https://react-native.canny.io/feature-requests?sort=trending)

## [Upvote here](https://react-native.canny.io/feature-requests/p/add-overflow-support-to-android) to bring the issue more attention.

Answer (score 2):

Following up on martinarroyo's answer.
Unfortunately he's right, currently there's no real better way, however, react-native 0.41 (not stable yet) promises to add android support for `overflow: visible` which is great news, because the workaround isn't all that fun...

Comment: 1 year later: did anything come from this?

Comment: @wahid_abdul I think it does. I just updated from 0.55 to 0.57 and one of the side effects was View's contents overflowing outside of it's boundaries. To fix that, I used `overflow: hidden` and it worked. Haven't tested this further.

Answer (score 2):

I had the similar problem and I found this amazing article on medium.com.
https://medium.com/entria/solving-view-overflow-in-android-reactnative-f961752a75cd

According to the article, you can use `react-native-view'overflow` library (a bridging header written to support the overflow in react-native android.

All you need to do is wrap the overflowcomponent in the `<ViewOverflow>`. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [react-native-view-overflow](https://github.com/entria/react-native-view-overflow) native module by Sibelius Seraphini.

Also, it seems this might be supported out of the box by React Native starting with version 0.57 according to [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/b81c8b51fc6fe3c2dece72e3fe500e175613c5d4) commit.

Answer (score -1):

This is a workaround I've been using since overflow: visible is not working correctly on Android.

https://medium.com/@jaredgoertzen/react-native-android-doesnt-render-overflow-styles-95e69154ebed