# ReactNative: overflow is not working for Android

Tags: android, react-native, overflow

I am using React-Native in my application. I used `overflow` to show a view which is outside the main view. Its working fine in iOS, but not in Android.

Here is my code:

```
 <View style={Style.parentStyle}>
<View
    style={[
        {
            height: barHeight,
            backgroundColor: color,
            overflow: "visible"
        },
        Style.mainStyle
    ]}
>
    <View
        style={[
            {
                borderRadius: shadowHeight,
                top: -borderRadiusBar,
                borderWidth: 1.0,
                borderColor: borderColor,
                backgroundColor: color,
                overflow: "visible"
            },
            Style.roundStyle
        ]}
    >
        <Text style={Style.otherstyle}>{player value}</Text>
    </View>
</View>
<Text style={Style.textStyle}>{name}</Text>
</View>;
```

Style:

```
  parentStyle: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        marginLeft: 1,
        marginRight: 2,
        justifyContent: 'flex-end',
        overflow: 'visible',
    },
    mainStyle: {
        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
        alignItems: 'center',
        borderRadius: 0,
        overflow: 'visible',
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

The `overflow` attribute is not supported on Android yet. But you can support the feature request [here](https://react-native.canny.io/feature-requests/p/add-overflow-support-to-android).

Duplicate of [Element overflow hidden in React-Native Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41912313/9360334)

Answer (score 1):

It's not working yet due to some native limitation, so all the overflow item will be hidden.