# Problem with border radius button react-native-elements

Tags: react-native, user-interface, react-native-elements

could you help me with this problem with the border radius of the button on the react native elements library?

I'm adding a border radius to the button, but its opacity remains rectangular, I don't understand why.

https://github.com/react-native-elements/react-native-elements/issues/2324

Comment: I think the problem has to do something with the overflow in RN .. wrap a View around it or check out this Question maybe : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41912313/element-overflow-hidden-in-react-native-android

Comment: not working :( @yesIamFaded

Comment: try this: adding "width: 100%" into your button.

Answer (score 4):

In ReactNative: 0.65, Elements: 3.4.2 and API 29 this still happens with me, but I found a solution setting overflow:'hidden' on View like this:

```
<View style={{
  width:"100%", 
  borderRadius: 30, 
  overflow: 'hidden' 
}}>
  <Button
    title="Login"
    type="solid"
    buttonStyle={{borderRadius: 30}}
  />
</View>
```

Comment: I used a similar approach, but instead of using a `View` component, I directly set the borderRadius and overflow properties inside `containerStyle` of the button itself: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73050493/2922751

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that using `buttonStyle` from RN Elements does the job without adding an extra view.

### Button Stylesheet `BUTTON_STYLES`:

In my case, I have added the `borderRadius` in a separate style sheet and referenced it in my button component.

```js
export const BUTTON_STYLES = StyleSheet.create({
  buttonStyle: {
    width: 'auto',
    height: 50,
    maxHeight: 50,
    maxWidth: 350,
    borderColor: 'black',
    borderWidth: 1,
  },
  titlePropsStyle: {
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    fontWeight: "normal"
  },
})
```

### Reusable Button Component

Below is the complete code for the reusable `ButtonComponent` I created using Button from React Native Element components and making sure it is applied on the `buttonStyles` property:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from '@rneui/base';

import FONTS from '@app/design/theme/fonts.theme';
import { BASE_COLORS } from '@app/design/theme/colors.theme';
import { BUTTON_STYLES } from './Button.styles';
import { IButtonComponent } from './Button.types';

export const ButtonComponent = ({
  variant = 'primary',
  label,
  disabled = false,
  onPress,
}: IButtonComponent) => {

  const { titlePropsStyle, buttonStyle } = BUTTON_STYLES;
  const buttonColorByVariant = variant === 'primary' ? BASE_COLORS.taekusBlack : BASE_COLORS.taekusWhite;
  const labelColorBtVariant = variant === 'primary' ? BASE_COLORS.taekusWhite : BASE_COLORS.taekusBlack;

  return (
    <Button
      title={label && label}
      onPress={(e) => onPress(e)}
      titleProps={{
        style: {
          ...titlePropsStyle,
          color: labelColorBtVariant
        }
      }}
      titleStyle={{ fontFamily: FONTS.regular }}
      buttonStyle={buttonStyle} // HERE it is referenced
      disabled={disabled}
      color={buttonColorByVariant}
    />
  );
};
```

### The output of the button is as follows:

**iOS:**

[image]

**Android:**

[image]