# ripple effect leaking at corners as if Pressable button has a borderRadius

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-component

I'm using Pressable for buttons after referring this docs [pressable docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/pressable#android_ripple-div-classlabel-androidandroiddiv)

Now I want to add ripple effect to the button but it is not working properly.

```
      <Pressable
        android_ripple={{color: 'red', borderless: false}}
        style={{backgroundColor: 'blue',borderRadius : 10}}>
        <Text style={{alignSelf: 'center'}}>Button</Text>
      </Pressable>
```

Ripple effect don't have border radius if button has radius.
it looks awkward that ripple effect corners go out of the curved radius.

[image: Ripple effect on Android]

Snack demonstrating the problem: https://snack.expo.dev/6U8dxxzLx

Comment: What's your RN version? It should be >=  0.63

Comment: What happens if you remove the `alignSelf: center` style?

Comment: Check this implementation https://reactnativeforyou.com/how-to-create-a-button-with-ripple-effect-in-react-native/

Comment: @wobsoriano yes i checked it, and it has same problem. that ripple effect don't have radius. if button has radius ripple will go out of corner and it looks awkward.

Comment: what about adding "overflow: 'hidden'" to Pressable style?

Comment: @D10S it will never work, i tried it. because ripple will be stopped by border of button underneath i think. even if it is curved it will be stopped by the real border only. you also check if you have time.

Comment: @naanu are you using expo? if yes, try to create a snack so we can just edit and play with it

Comment: @wobsoriano no sir, i'm working on live project. i don't even know what expo means. I'm new to react-native just started from 2 days.

Comment: try wrapping the component with a View with "overflow: 'hidden'"

Comment: @D10S i tried that and is the same. problem not fixed

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Nothing worked for me, So I solved this myself.

- pressable should be wrapped in a view
- view must have margin not padding
- border radius must be on view not on pressable
- pressable component must have padding not margin
- then add ripple by *android_ripple={{color: 'black', borderless: true}}* to pressable.

```
<View style={styles.buttonView}>
              <Pressable
                onPress={() => {}}
                android_ripple={{color: 'black', borderless: true}}
                style={styles.loginButton}>
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Login</Text>
              </Pressable>
            </View>
```

```
buttonView: {
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    borderRadius: 10,
    elevation: 25,
    margin: 10,
  },
  loginButton: {
    height: 50,
    backgroundColor: '#0f4c75',
    padding: 10,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 16,
    textTransform: 'uppercase',
    fontFamily: 'sans-serif-light',
  },
```

Update:-
***Floating pressable component with ripple leakage fixed***

```
<View style={{
                position: 'absolute',
                bottom: 250,
                borderRadius: 50,
                overflow: 'hidden',
                alignSelf: 'center'
            }}>
                <Pressable
                    style={{
                        height: 60,
                        width: 60,
                        borderRadius: 50,
                        backgroundColor: 'red',
                        justifyContent: 'center',
                        alignItems: 'center',
                        elevation: 4,
                    }}
                    android_ripple={{
                        color: 'black',
                    }}
                    onPress={() => { console.log('om') }}>
                    <Text>O</Text>
                </Pressable>
            </View>
```

Comment: sadly it makes hitSlop completely unusable.

Comment: it seems that an elevation is mandatory (otherwise an overflow works too) and I don't get the why

Answer (score 28):

You can wrap pressable into View and pass borderRadius:10 and overflow:'hidden' to View style.

```
<View style={{ borderRadius: 10, overflow: 'hidden' }}>
    <Pressable
      android_ripple={{ color: 'red', borderless: false, }}
      style={{ backgroundColor: 'blue', borderRadius: 10 }}>
      <Text style={{ alignSelf: 'center' }}>Button</Text>
    </Pressable>
  </View>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add this to the style,

```
style={{ overflow: 'hidden' }}
```

And in the config, just add these two properties

```
android_ripple={{ color: 'red', borderless: false, foreground: true }}
```

Comment: Best answer! This works!

Comment: This affects the text on the button, it also covered by ripple.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the other solution don't cover all edge cases... I needed to wrap the view 2 times to manage `elevation` and `shadow` on iOS. (The button is in absolute position also).

```
export const PNFloatingButton = ({ children, ...props }) => {
    return (
        <View style={thisStyles.shadow}>
            <View style={thisStyles.parentContainer}>
                <Pressable style={thisStyles.button}
                           android_ripple={{ borderless: false, color: "#0F0" }}>
                    <Text>Button</Text>
                </PNPressable>
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}

const thisStyles = StyleSheet.create({
    shadow: {
        shadowColor: '#000',
        shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
        shadowOpacity: 0.4,
        shadowRadius: 4,
        width: 56,
        height: 56,
        position: 'absolute',
        elevation: 2,
        right: 0,
        bottom: 0,
    },
    button: {
        padding: 4,
        backgroundColor: "#F00",
    },
    parentContainer: {
        // Pressable has issues with borderRadius on the ripple on android
        overflow: "hidden",
        borderRadius: 40,
    },
})
```

Comment: I would say this is great help as you have implement another view for shadow. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For those that are using the `Button` element I found a simple workaround. Since this problem happens always when border od the button is changed (like became rounded) I just pass to the `containerStyle` of the button all the props + my button border radius. I add also the overflow property with hidden attribute.

*Some little context: `myButtonStyle` is the style I want to apply to that button. If it's null, I'll apply a default style. Same for `myContainerStyle`.*

The function inplemented before return():

```
function fixRippleBorder() {
  const borderRadius = myButtonStyle
    ? EStyleSheet.flatten(myButtonStyle).borderRadius
    : EStyleSheet.flatten(defaultButtonStyle).borderRadius;

  return {
    borderRadius: borderRadius,
    overflow: 'hidden',
  };
}
```

The button itself:

```
<Button
  containerStyle={[
    myContainerStyle ?? defaultContainerStyle,
    fixRippleBorder(),
  ]}
  buttonStyle={myButtonStyle ?? defaultButtonStyle}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the style `overFlow: 'hidden'` to a view that wraps around your pressable object as long as that view also contains your borderRadius. Below is an example of a file I worked on recently that does this

```js
import React from 'react';
import {Pressable, View, Text, StyleSheet, Platform} from 'react-native';

export default function CategoryGridTile({title, color, onPress}) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.gridItem}>
      <Pressable
        android_ripple={{color: '#ccc'}}
        style={({pressed}) => [
          styles.button,
          pressed ? styles.buttonPressed : null,
        ]}
        onPress={onPress}>
        <View style={[styles.innerContainer, {backgroundColor: color}]}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
        </View>
      </Pressable>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  gridItem: {
    flex: 1,
    margin: 16,
    height: 150,
    borderRadius: 8,
    elevation: 4,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    shadowColor: 'black',
    shadowOpacity: 0.25,
    shadowOffset: {width: 0, height: 2},
    shadowRadius: 8,
    overflow: 'hidden',
  },
  button: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  buttonPressed: {
    opacity: 0.5,
  },
  innerContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 16,
    borderRadius: 8,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  title: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 18,
  },
});
```